# a complicated question about double improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

how to evaluate $$\iint_{y\ge x^2+1}{dx\,dy\over{x^4+y^2}}$$

My solution: the initial intergral

$$
=2\int_0^\infty \left(\int_{x^2+1}^\infty {dy\over {x^4+y^2}}\right)\,dx
= \int_0^\infty  \int_{x^2+1}^\infty {{1\over{x^2} }d({y\over {x^2}})\over{1+({y\over x^2}})^2}
$$

$$
= \int_0^\infty {1\over x^2} \left({\pi\over 2} - \arctan\left(1+{1\over x^2}\right) \right)dx,
$$

I feel confused here. Can somebody give me other methods to solve the question?

Comment: So, the second step of the integral is blatantly wrong, because there can't be a single $d(\frac{y}{x^2})$ when there is two integral signs. That simply is not allowed.

Comment: They should be in the first integral,can you help me fix it?

Comment: OK, I've done some further edits; I hope it's correct now.

Comment: @tiandiao123 To clarify, I mean the integral with the $d(y/x^2)$ doesn't make sense - it is simply wrong notationally.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot

Comment: you mean when x=0,d(y/x^2) doesn't make sense? yes, That's a problem, that's why I want to find another method.

Comment: Maple is quite comfortable with the double integral in its original form and gives the answer$$\pi\sqrt{2\sqrt2-2}\ .$$Don't ask me how though ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a wrong way to write your double integral. You have to change the domain. Let $u=x,v=y-x^2$. Then your domain $D=\{(x,y): y\ge x^2+1\}$ can be changed into $D'=\{(u,v): -\infty< u<\infty, 1\le v<\infty\}$.
Note
$$\det\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}=1$$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
\iint_{D}{dx\,dy\over{x^4+y^2}}&=&\iint_{D'}\frac{1}{u^4+(u^2+v)^2}dudv\\
&=&2\int_0^\infty\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{u^4+(u^2+v)^2}dvdu\\
&=&2\int_0^\infty\int_{u^2+1}^\infty\frac{1}{w^2+u^4}dwdu\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{\pi-2\arctan(1+\frac{1}{u^2})}{u^2}du
\end{eqnarray*}
which can be evaluated by integration-by-parts formula as $\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}\pi$.

Comment: That dangling $\pi$ is just begging for confusion.

Comment: The dangling $\pi$ is from $\arctan\infty$.

Comment: I believe he meant that this would be better written as $\pi \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2} -2}$ instead of how you presented it. By the way, nice answer. Upvoted!